# Mp4 to dynamic adaptive hls with multiple bitrates using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, adaptive-bitrate

I tried converting mp4 video to HLS for online streaming which I have successfully done using FFmpeg.

Command:

```
ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/file_conversion/heli.mp4 -map 0 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -s 640x360 -c:v libx264 -b:v 500k -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 320k -hls_list_size 0 -start_number 0 -hls_init_time 0 -hls_time 2  -f hls /var/www/html/file_conversion/hlstest2/heli.m3u8
```

But now I am trying to convert the same video with multiple bitrates for dynamic adaptive streaming.

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating HLS variants with FFMPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225026/creating-hls-variants-with-ffmpeg)

Comment: See also: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs

Comment: Thank you for your response @slhck i have already created 3 different playlists for high mid and low resolution the question was how can i combine them all into one to create a master playlist with multiple bitrates having .m3u8 for adaptive bitrate streaming i appreciate your effort for helping me out

Comment: Read the answer from the other question. There it says how to combine the playlists into one `.m3u8`.

Comment: just like creating a dash manifest which handles dynamic streaming for different bitrates

Comment: thanks man highly appreciated  going to read that once again more carefully

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I was having the same doubt, and found this article:**
https://dev.to/nodir_dev/transcode-video-source-to-hls-playlist-format-for-video-on-demand-vod-streaming-3h99

After making transcoding files, just create a *.m3u8 file, with the following content:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=375000,RESOLUTION=640x360
360_out.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=750000,RESOLUTION=854x480
480_out.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2000000,RESOLUTION=1280x720
720_out.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=3500000,RESOLUTION=1920x1080
1080_out.m3u8
```

now just send this file to the streams.

My HLS folder:

[image: image_folder]

The content of the master file:

[image: content_of_master_file]

*I made the transcoding two resolutions: 1280x720 and 640x480*

**- Author of the article: Nodirbek Sharipov**